# PostgreSQL too slow selecting 1 billion records in a table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, big-data

I created a PostgreSQL db in Google Cloud SQL and have a single table that stores 1 billion records

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    dt DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    cnt SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);
CREATE INDEX user_id_idx ON a(user_id);
CREATE INDEX dt_idx ON a(dt);
CREATE INDEX user_id_dt_idx ON a(user_id, dt);
```

The result from `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a WHERE user_id = 1 AND dt BETWEEN ('2021-08-01' AND '2021-12-31')` is 10 million rows which is pretty big.

What I want is to count `id` with some conditions like below.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM(
    SELECT t.id, SUM(t.count) cnt_sum
    FROM (
        SELECT id, count
        FROM a
        WHERE user_id = 1 AND dt BETWEEN ('2021-08-01' AND '2021-12-31')
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.id
) t2
WHERE t2.cnt_sum > 1 AND t2.cnt_sum < 100
```

The execution plan is below.

```
Aggregate  (cost=432974.05..432974.06 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=76873.827..76873.829 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=199160, temp read=172244 written=172504
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=430508.09..432967.22 rows=546 width=41) (actual time=58606.309..76050.907 rows=9089942 loops=1)
        Group Key: a.id
        Filter: ((sum(a.count) > 1) AND (sum(a.count) < 100))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1010317
        Buffers: shared hit=199160, temp read=172244 written=172504
        ->  Sort  (cost=430508.09..430781.32 rows=109295 width=35) (actual time=58606.287..70580.733 rows=10100259 loops=1)
              Sort Key: a.id
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 454704kB
              Buffers: shared hit=199160, temp read=172244 written=172504
              ->  Index Scan using user_id_idx on a  (cost=0.57..418372.26 rows=109295 width=35) (actual time=0.025..3334.426 rows=10100259 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = 778)
                    Filter: ((dt >= '2021-06-01'::date) AND (dt <= '2022-01-20'::date))
                    Buffers: shared hit=199160
Planning Time: 0.184 ms
Execution Time: 76930.444 ms
```

However, This query took over 80 seconds to complete.

Is there any thing to make it perform better?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just added the plan.

Comment: Well, you used `format json` not `format text` as I suggested. The JSON format is not intended to be read by humans. And you did not use the `analyze` option either, so we can't tell where the performance is lost

Comment: I'm curious why it isn't using the multicolumn index.  Is it bloated?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh! I'm sorry about that! This is my first time to share a query plan in Stackoverflow. I just updated the plan as you suggessted. Thanks!

Comment: When was the last time you `VACUUM ANALYZE`d this table?

Comment: @mustaccio I've never done that. do i need to do this periodically? like every day?

Comment: The main culprit is the fact that the GROUP BY can't be done in memory; `Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 454704kB` which takes about 65 seconds of the total runtime. The typical way to solve this, is to increase `work_mem` but that is probably unrealistic given the size of the table (and the fact that it's a hosting environment). Another way to solve this, is to get faster disks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you mean "get faster disks" SSD? I already created the database with SSD. Does the index I created work fine? because I thought the index "user_id_dt_idx" would be used instead of "user_id_idx"

Comment: My PostgreSQL (13) does not accept "SELECT id, count FROM a WHERE user_id = 1 AND dt BETWEEN ('2021-08-01' AND '2021-12-31')".  I have to remove the parentheses from around the dates.

Comment: @EricLee the optimizer thought that by using user_id_idx, he'd only need to read 100K records, while in reality there were 10M.  So, analyzing might be a good idea.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille do you mean that the optimizer choose the wrong index? then how do i make it work correct? Thanks!

Comment: @EricLee,  Reading the second sentence of my last comment might be a first step.  Earlier on, mustaccio gave you the same advice.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Thanks for the advices. I will look deep into your comments.